# Twitter image bot posts every 2 hours

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, twython

This is a twitter image bot that is called on every two hours to post a picture from a folder, the files are numbered consecutively and the current number is stored in a text file so it can stay constant between the runs. The image file types vary between .jpg and .gif and i dont know how to account for this in the picture() function of my code.

```
import os
from twython import Twython 
from twython import TwythonStreamer

APP_KEY = ''
APP_SECRET = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

f = open('pictures.txt', 'r+')
z = f.read()

def picture():
    picture = open('/0/' + 'picture' + str(z))
    f.write(str(z)+'\n')
    global z
    z += 1
    promote(picture)
    f.write(z)
    f.close


def promote(photo):
    twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    twitter.update_status_with_media(status='', media=photo)

picture()
```

Comment: What error message does it give when you run it. Add that bit of information as well

Comment: @cmrnrb - did you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24462987/21945) to your previous, extremely similar, question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your previous question has been put on hold, I post this answer again.

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to find files matching a prefix, [imghdr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html#module-imghdr) to check the file type (twitter doesn't support all image files), and make sure that you convert the image sequence number to an int when you read it in, and to a string when you update the file. The file update requires seeking to the beginning of the file first, and this assumes that the sequence number will always increase.

```
import imghdr
from glob import glob

SUPPORTED_IMG_TYPES = 'gif jpeg png'.split()
IMG_SEQ_FILE = '/0/pictures.txt'
GLOB_PATTERN = '/0/picture%d.*'

def send_to_twitter(filename):
    print "sent %s to twitter" % filename
    return True

with open(IMG_SEQ_FILE, 'r+') as f:
    seq = int(f.readline().strip())
    for name in glob(GLOB_PATTERN % seq):
        img_type = imghdr.what(name)
        if img_type in SUPPORTED_IMG_TYPES:
            if send_to_twitter(name):
                f.seek(0)
                seq += 1
                f.write(str(seq))
                break
        else:
            if not img_type:
               print "%s is not an image file" % name
            else:
               print "%s unsupported image type: %s" % (name, img_type)
```

All you need to do is add your code to send the image file data to twitter.

Comment: when i run this nothing past
    for name in glob seems to run, nothing is printed and the text file isnt updated at all? thank you

Comment: Are there any files matching the glob pattern in /0, e.g is there a file named "picture1.jpg"? Have you initialised the sequence file, and is it in /0/pictures.txt?

Comment: yeah i have the pictures and i have the pictures file which has only the number '0' in it

Comment: Is there a file named `/0/picture0.jpg`, or `/0/picture0.gif` etc? If so, does your application have permission to read the file?

Comment: yeah those files are in there and it was able to read and write to the file before when i had some other code

Comment: Try adding some `print` statements to your code, e.g. after `seq` is read from the file, and also print out the value of `glob(GLOB_PATTERN % seq)` before the for loop starts

Comment: yeah i tried that earlier, it could print the seq and it could print the file path but it cant print anything further, like the image type

Comment: Well. what was the result of `print glob(GLOB_PATTERN % seq)` ?

Comment: when i print `seq` it prints 0, when i print `(GLOB_PATTERN % seq)` it prints `/0/picture0.*` but when i print `glob(GLOB_PATTERN % seq)` it prints `[]`

Comment: What is the output of `ls /0/picture0.*` ? How about `ls /0`? Are you sure that you have read access to those files for the user that is executing your script?